# PHP preg_match beetween infinity solid rules

Tags: php, preg-match, infinity

I need something like

> preg_match((element1)(.*?)**if-**(Quantity:)([^0])**-return-TRUE**, $str);

but `(.*?)` ruined everything, because he skips every `(Quantity:)(0)` before finds `(Quantity:)([^0])` from another element for example `(item2)` going next to `(element1)`

> ***element1*** random:random Quantity:0 element2 random:random Quantity:0 item1 random:random Quantity:0 item2 random:random **Quantity:999**

So how can i say php to do strict on `(Quantity:)([^0])` and return TRUE, but if it's `(Quantity:)(0)` to return FALSE and not to play with me doing infinity regonising  `(Quantity:)(0)` as `(.*?)` too?

**UPDATE LIVE PREVIEW** this is what i want http://www.regexr.com/3a3jn this is what i don't want to happen http://www.regexr.com/3a3jq place it as text to links examples and you'll see what i am talking about

> {"skuAttr":"14:200001438#8;5:100014064","skuPropIds":"200001438,100014064","skuVal":{"actSkuBulkCalPrice":"3.05","actSkuBulkPrice":"3.05","actSkuCalPrice":"3.47","actSkuDisplayBulkPrice":"US
>   $3.05","actSkuMultiCurrencyBulkPrice":"3.05","actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"3.47","actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"3.47","actSkuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US
>   $3.47","actSkuPrice":"3.47","availQuantity":999,"bulkOrder":5,"inventory":999,"isActivity":true,"skuBulkCalPrice":"3.32","skuBulkPrice":"3.32","skuCalPrice":"3.77","skuDisplayBulkPrice":"US
>   $3.32","skuMultiCurrencyBulkPrice":"3.32","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"3.77","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"3.77","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US
>   $3.77","skuPrice":"3.77"}},{"skuAttr":"14:200001438#8;5:100014065","skuPropIds":"200001438,100014065","skuVal":{"actSkuBulkCalPrice":"3.05","actSkuBulkPrice":"3.05","actSkuCalPrice":"3.47","actSkuDisplayBulkPrice":"US
>   $3.05","actSkuMultiCurrencyBulkPrice":"3.05","actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"3.47","actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"3.47","actSkuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US
>   $3.47","actSkuPrice":"3.47","availQuantity":0,"bulkOrder":5,"inventory":0,"isActivity":true,"skuBulkCalPrice":"3.32","skuBulkPrice":"3.32","skuCalPrice":"3.77","skuDisplayBulkPrice":"US
>   $3.32","skuMultiCurrencyBulkPrice":"3.32","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"3.77","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"3.77","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US
>   $3.77","skuPrice":"3.77"}}

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear, show us some sample strings and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I found soultion

```
preg_match('/14:200001438#8;5:100014065.*?availQuantity":(\d+)/', $str);
```

and next we check if `(\d+)` equal 0 or any number

**LIVE EXAMPLE** http://www.regexr.com/3a3k0